# Is it a good practice to pass object to Vuex mutation?

Tags: vuex

E.g. in store I have multiple fields.

```
loads: [{
            name: 'Example load',
            fields: {
                nu: { name: 'nu', variable: 'nu', field_id: 'tower_base_loads.extreme_load_abnormal_dlc', value: null, unit: e('UnitOfMeasure.COEFF') },
                pz: { name: 'Pz', variable: 'pz', field_id: 'tower_base_loads.extreme_load_abnormal_dlc', value: null, unit: e('UnitOfMeasure.KILONEWTONS') },
                px: { name: 'Px', variable: 'px', field_id: 'tower_base_loads.extreme_load_abnormal_dlc', value: null, unit: e('UnitOfMeasure.KILONEWTONS') },
                mz: { name: 'Mz', variable: 'mz', field_id: 'tower_base_loads.extreme_load_abnormal_dlc', value: null, unit: e('UnitOfMeasure.KILONEWTON_METERS') },
                my_neg: { name: 'My_neg', variable: 'my_neg', field_id: 'tower_base_loads.extreme_load_abnormal_dlc', value: null, unit: e('UnitOfMeasure.KILONEWTON_METERS') },
            }
        }]
```

so I make update to those fields with this mutation:

```
mutations: {
    UPDATE_FIELD_VALUE: (state, {field, value}) => field.value = value,
},
```

is it a good practice? Is there a better way?

Comment: That's correct and it's what you want to do. It's also what you get from using the **vuex-map-fields** library which handles a lot of that for you and will ultimately makes your life easier (mostly in large scale projects)

Answer (score 0):

If those fields are used together and have high [cohesion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/software-engineering-coupling-and-cohesion/) then it's fine updating them all at once. If they don't then you should consider creating a different mutation for each field, and just call each mutation separately on your actions. If you group your updates with data that are used regularly together you increase the **reusability** of the mutation functions.

There is no bad or good practice because **this is a design decision**, you always have **trade-offs** on those decisions.

I would recommend thinking about your data being updated, if they seem to update always all together then your implementation is fine.